# Finding other vectors that form a basis

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

The question I'm working on is:

*For the given vectors $v, w$ in $\mathbb R^4$, find other vectors $u_1, ..., u_n$ such that {${v, w, u_1,...,u_n}$} form a basis of $\mathbb R^4$.*

$v = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \\ 3 \\ 4 \end{bmatrix}$ and $w = \begin{bmatrix} 4 \\ 3 \\ 2 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$

I'm not sure how I'd find *other* vectors that form a basis for a subspace. 
I know the first step is to get the matrix given into Reduced Row Echelon Form, and that all the vectors in a basis are linearly independent. However, putting these two together and reducing leaves:

$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$

Which I'm not sure what to do with to find a basis.

Comment: Put them in as row vectors, not column vectors. When row reducing you find a basis for the row-space not column space (the nonzero rows in REF form a basis of the row-space). Then it should be easy to pick two vectors which have the necessary leading 1's.

Comment: @DavidP when you say the non-zero rows, you don't include the pivot rows correct? So after row reducing with row vectors, I have -1, -2 in one row and 2, 3 in the other (excluding pivot rows). That forms a basis. I'm confused by your "pick two vectors which have the necessary leading 1's". What necessary leading 1's?

Comment: @DavidP , my mistake, the basis of the row space of these vectors should be [1, 0, -1, 2] and [0,1,2,3]. I confused myself! However, I'm still confused on how I would pick two vectors with "the necessary leading 1's".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the determinant
$$
\begin{vmatrix}
1&4&a&w\\
2&3&b&x\\
3&2&c&y\\
4&1&d&z
\end{vmatrix}\ne0.
$$
Row reduction: If we subtract the previous row from each row, we get
$$
\begin{vmatrix}
1&4&a&w\\
1&-1&b-a&x-w\\
1&-1&c-b&y-x\\
1&-1&d-c&z-y
\end{vmatrix}.
$$
Repeat, and we get
$$
\begin{vmatrix}
1&4&a&w\\
0&-5&b-2a&x-2w\\
0&0&c-2b&y-2x\\
0&0&d-2c&z-2y
\end{vmatrix}
=
-5\,\begin{vmatrix}
c-2b&y-2x\\ d-2c&z-2y
\end{vmatrix}.
$$
We need, then, this last $2\times 2$ determinant to be nonzero. If we take $b=x=c=y=0$, we have 
$$
(c-2b)(z-2y)-(d-2c)(y-2x)=-dy.
$$
It is then enough to take $d=y=1$. So, 
$$
\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\0\\1\end{bmatrix},\ \ \ \begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}
$$
foot the bill.

Comment: Thank you for your thorough answer! However, I was told this was possible without determinants, and I'm curious as to how it could be done without. Is it possible with row spaces as DavidP suggested above?

Comment: It's the same thing. What I'm doing inside the determinant is row reduction, so you want $c-2b=1$, $y-2x=0$, $d-2c=0$, $z-2y=1$ (or with the zeroes exchanged with the ones). You can then make a choice of the coefficients that satisfy those equations; my choice is one of them.